# Swift - force square photo from library and camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, gallery, square

I'm building an app and I need to FORCE the user to upload square pictures (just like Instagram does), however I'd like to avoid programming an interface from scratch as we're short in time.

It is important to note that the USER must CHOOSE which part of the image he/she wants to show, so cropping the image programatically without asking the user is out of the question.

I've managed to get this to work via camera, however via library I can't seem to force the user to use a square image. Here's the code I have:

```
func presentGallery(){
    // from library
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then on my imagepickercontroller:

```
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
```

However I don't get the desired result. It would be fine if the "minimum zoom" was to show 100% of the height of the image, or if I could add a white/black background to the top and bottom of the image.

Here's the problem: [image]

Instead of something like this:

[image]

My app needs to work starting from iOS7.

Comment: You can use the first extension to return an squared image. If it doesn't solve your problem please let me know so I can reopen your question.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for your help, however using your code, the image gets cropped. it is important to show all the information the user wants. This is why I need either of these two things:
1) Add "pixels" to the top/bottom or left/right of the image, in order to make it square
2) Force the user to select a squared picture from the gallery viewer (second image I uploaded)

Comment: to make the image from the camera square you will always need to crop it, anyways I've reopened the question.

Comment: I've managed to get it working with the following code: 

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: maxDimension, height: maxDimension), false, 0.0);
            image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, image.size.width/2-image.size.height/2, image.size.width, image.size.height))
            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return newImage

However now I'd like to add white background to the rectangle, that'd be all I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some sort of check to make sure that the picture is square if they're picking from their library.

Once you get the image (using `imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`), then get the image with `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`. Once you've done this, perform the check:

```
if (image.size.height != image.size.width) // Show some alert
```

---

What might be an even better solution is creating a view which allows the user to pick any photo, and then choose a square part of the photo to import into your app, like Instagram does.

Comment: Not a very user-friendly approach I'm afraid. It doesn't feel right to show an alert after selecting an image, saying the image you selected is wrong

Comment: I updated my answer with another more user-friendly suggestion like what Instagram does!

Comment: Thanks Steven for your response, yes, I'd be looking for what you added, however I would need some help implementing it (basically I stated in my question I needed what instagram offers haha)